# how to fix php for loop output displaying 1?

Tags: php

Here is my php code given below when I run it in my browser its display 1 continuously. My question is why its show like this? After execution its displays a fatal error : maximum execution time is exceeded. what is that?

```
    <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i+1) { 
            echo $i." ";
        }
    ?>
```

Give me proper answer. Make me sure that what is the  execution time of php code?
TIA

Comment: Is `$i+1` a legal construct in the language? Most interpreters just print garbage for that code.

Comment: That is a silly mistake. just have a look at the below answers, But to answer the final point, its up-to you that whats the time limit that you had chosen. you can set the script execution time as : ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

Comment: use `for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)`

Answer (score 4):

`$i+1` does not increment the value of `$i`. It only adds 1 to what is in `$i` but it does not assign it back to `$i`. Your loop does this:

```
$i = 1
while ($i<=5) { 
    echo $i." ";

    $i+1;
}
```

`$i+1` on it's own doesn't do anything.

You need something like `$i = $i + 1`. Or for short `$i += 1`. Or even shorter and better: `$i++`.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { 
    echo $i . " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$i++` not `$i+1`, `$i++ is $i=$i+1`

Answer (score 1):

It is because of $i+1 in for loop. This is basically an expression and it produces a result but you never assign this result to $i. Therefore you would rather do something like $i = $i + 1 or, in real life, use [incrementation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) $i++. So the final code will looks like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  echo $i." ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { 
echo $i." ";
}
?>
```

because first you must set value for $i

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
<?php
    for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { 
      echo $i." ";
    }
?>
```

Now you just say `1 + 1` but you don't assign it to anything. You could use `$i = $i + 1` but it's the same as `$i++`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { 
      echo $i." ";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in a for loop, every turn you need to increase value of $i. but you forgot to increase value of $i. You wrote $i +1 but it needs to be assigned with new value of $i.

In short, you should change $i +1 to $i = $i +1 or $i ++

the right code:

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i = $i+1) { 
echo $i." ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of `$i` in the loop. Either `$i =$i +1` or `$i++` instead of `$i + 1` will do.

Answer (score -1):

You've problem in printing the line. It should look like

```
<?php
   for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { 
   echo $i;
   }
?>
```